# Chrome autofill with MDL for type="password"

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, material-design, material-design-lite

I'm currently working on my website with the MDL (Material Design Lite) from google and I have a little problem.

[image]

As you can see, the stars are in the good place but the password stay here (he is moving after any click or press on the keyboard)

My code is really simple :

```
<div class="mdl-textfield mdl-js-textfield mdl-textfield--floating-label">
    <input class="mdl-textfield__input" type="text" name="mail">
    <label class="mdl-textfield__label">Adresse Email</label>
</div>
<div class="mdl-textfield mdl-js-textfield mdl-textfield--floating-label">
    <input id="test" class="mdl-textfield__input" type="password" name="password">
    <label class="mdl-textfield__label">Password</label>
</div>
```

The code is usual and basic. Problem is, in MDL (Link here : https://www.getmdl.io/components/index.html#textfields-section) there is nothing for password type, so I always got the problem from before.

I want to keep the chrome autofill for my client so disabled it is not a option. Is there any way to change this problem ?

Thank's !

Comment: I guess `id=test` is not needed. `name=` is enough for js to identify. Removing `id` may fix autofill.

Comment: No it didnt change anything

Comment: Actually, what do you want? Disable autofill in password box or enable it?

Comment: Oops, sorry for the late answer. 
I want to use a password with the type="text". If you check my picture there is kind of a display bug there

Comment: `type=text` ?? I can see your codes as `type=password` :/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

HTML

```
<div class="mdl-textfield mdl-js-textfield mdl-textfield--floating-label">
  <input class="mdl-textfield__input" type="password" id="password" required name="password">
  <label class="mdl-textfield__label" for="password"></label>
</div>
```

CSS Fix

```
.mdl-textfield--floating-label input[type=password]:-webkit-autofill ~ label {
  transform: translate3d(0, -20px, 0);
  visibility: hidden;
}

.mdl-textfield--floating-label input[type=password]:-webkit-autofill ~ label:after {
  content: 'Password';
  visibility: visible;
  left: 0;
  transform: translate3d(0, -20px, 0);
  background: transparent;
  color: inherit;
}
```

Change the color and maybe the px offset to suit your needs

---

JQuery solution that works when the type is not "password"

```
  $.each($('.mdl-textfield__input'), function() {
    $(this).parent().get(0).MaterialTextfield.checkDirty();
  });
```

---

Another jquery workaround is to force the focus on the input field if autofill is detected. You should put this inside $(document).ready

```
  setTimeout(function() {
    try { if ( $('#password:-webkit-autofill').length > 0 ) $('#password').focus(); }
    catch (error) { console.log(error); }
  }, 25);
```

Comment: hey @Nicolas_LeBot i've updated the answer after reading http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32579980/mdl-jquery-label-overlaps-the-content-into-a-input-field

Answer (score 2):

```
setTimeout(function() {
  $.each($('.mdl-textfield'), function() {
    var input = $(this).find("input");
    var len = input.val().length;
    var type = input.attr("type");

    if (len > 0 || type == "password")
      $(this).addClass("is-dirty");
  });
}, 100);
```

Works for both text and password fields. One downside is that password fields will always be marked as dirty, empty or not.

Answer (score 0):

use `for='id'` in your labels?

```
<label class="mdl-textfield__label" for='test'>Password</label>
```

Comment: Doesn't change anything =/ 
It's just a display bug but i really don't know how to solve it :(

Comment: try using a different browser?

Comment: Hum, no problem on firefox actually ... could it come from the autofill ? I don't want to disabled it obviously

Answer (score 0):

It's not good, it's not clean but it works. This solution relies on ids

```
$(document).ready( function() {

    setTimeout(function(){
        $("#password").focus();
        componentHandler.upgradeDom();

        if($("#username").val().length === 0) { 
            $("#password").blur(); 
            componentHandler.upgradeDom();
        }
    },100);
});
```

If you try to check the length of password it would always give 0 so you can check the length of the username field instead (if it's full it would be a pleasure to have the cursor there even if there's no password).